# how to fetch Mysql response for rows matched?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

[workbench output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m03kD.png)

Matched row is not included in mysql pydocument

- MySQLCursor.column_names, MySQLCursor.column_names Property
- MySQLCursor.description, MySQLCursor.description Property
- MySQLCursor.lastrowid, MySQLCursor.lastrowid Property
- MySQLCursor.rowcount, MySQLCursor.rowcount Property
- MySQLCursor.statement, MySQLCursor.statement Property
- MySQLCursor.with_rows, MySQLCursor.with_rows Property

Comment: I don't think MySQL has a public API to get that information. I think WorkBench uses some internal, undocumented mechanism for it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using client_flags.

CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS: Return the number of found (matched) rows, not the number of changed row and reflects to `MySQLCursor.rowcount`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html